# Commit live with subversion

Tags: c#, svn, commit, live

Is there a good library in c# that can check against a ftp and subversion and then upload the updated files (when comparing against a given rev.)?

Forbidden files to upload should be given. (like local web.config, dev files etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the subversion part, [sharp svn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) is a C# binding for svn.
For the FTP part, you could use "normal" C# code (or have a look at [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftplib.aspx).)

Comment: I was looking for a complete solution where you could just tell the component where the ftp is (with pass/user) and point to the svn.